# Mutate multiple columns to fill according to condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to fill in emails from different registrations (relatioships) as an option.Which way I could do this? This is a tiny example, I'm working with a huge dataset.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(id1 = c("20940512", "15595376", "26638338", "05300340", "42874317"),
             id2 = c("3345359", "3345359", "3345359", "3345359", "3345359"),
             email = c("exmp1@mail.com", "exmp2@mail.com", "-", "exmp3@mail.com", "-"),
             isValidEmail = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0))


# OUTPUT

> df
# A tibble: 5 x 4
id1      id2     email          isValidEmail
<chr>    <chr>   <chr>                 <dbl>
1 20940512 3345359 exmp1@mail.com            1
2 15595376 3345359 exmp2@mail.com            1
3 26638338 3345359 -                         0
4 05300340 3345359 exmp3@mail.com            1
5 42874317 3345359 -                         0


# I'm looking for a way of doing this starting from the dataset exemplified above

# A tibble: 5 x 7
id1      id2     email          validEmail1    validEmail2    validEmail3    isValidEmail
<chr>    <chr>   <chr>          <chr>          <chr>          <chr>                 <dbl>
1 20940512 3345359 exmp1@mail.com exmp1@mail.com exmp2@mail.com exmp3@mail.com            1
2 15595376 3345359 exmp2@mail.com exmp1@mail.com exmp2@mail.com exmp3@mail.com            1
3 26638338 3345359 -              exmp1@mail.com exmp2@mail.com exmp3@mail.com            0
4 05300340 3345359 exmp3@mail.com exmp1@mail.com exmp2@mail.com exmp3@mail.com            1
5 42874317 3345359 -              exmp1@mail.com exmp2@mail.com exmp3@mail.com            0
```

Edit:
the isValidEmail column is important because it indicates whether there is a valid email in the email field, which may have "-" (or some invalid format, such as xx@xx.xx), in this scenario, what I'm trying to do is: for the relationship id1 26638338 id2 3345359 whose isValidEmail is 0, bring in other columns all the emails for id2 (3345359) found for relationships other than id1 (26638338)

I'm actually looking for how I can do this because I have no idea how to.

Comment: What have you tried so far with mutate()? It looks like you're just filling new columns with generic from your desired output.

Comment: Could you explain more about the logic? Do you want to limit it to 3 `validEmail` columns, or do you want more if there are more? Is `isValidEmail` relevant to the logic? Is it possible to "chain" relationships--if `id1 = A` co-occurs with `id2 = B`, and `id1 = B` co-occurs with `id2 = C`, and `id1 = C` has a valid email, should that be associated with `A` too (via B)?

Comment: I'll try to explain: the isValidEmail column is important because it indicates whether there is a valid email in the email field, which may have "-" (or some invalid format, such as xx@xx.xx), in this scenario, what I'm trying to do is: for the relationship id1 26638338 id2 3345359 whose isValidEmail is 0, bring in other columns all the (valid) emails for id2 (3345359) found for relationships other than id1 (26638338)

Comment: @GregorThomas I want more if there are more, and yes I think it does make sense!

Comment: *"bring in other columns all the (valid) emails for id2 (3345359) found for relationships other than id1 (26638338)"* okay, so you only want to bring in valid emails from other `id2` values. If `id1 (26638338)` appears in other rows, you don't want them included?

Comment: @GregorThomas  The main idea behind this is: imagine that you have several records of your customers. Id1 would be the registration number and id2 would be the customer document. In some registrations, for some reason there is blank email or an invalid email. Marketing needs to run a campaign, so we need to bring all valid emails found within the table, for different relationships, but in the same table. Thus, the relationship with register id1 26638338 where there is an empty email can be viewed with emails from other id1 (registers) according to id2 (document)

Comment: Does that makes sense? It's a bit abstract to explain, I'm sorry and thanks for the attention

Comment: I'm trying to work out the differences between `id1` and `id2`. We can view the relationships as a graph, where each `id` value is a node, and the relationships between them are edges. (The `igraph` package can make it easy to do the types of things you ask if we treat the data this well.) What I'm trying to figure out is if it should be a *directed graph* or not...

Comment: So basically, if `id1 = A` and `id2 = B` co-occur on one row with a valid email address, then (a) I think that valid email should be filled in on all other rows where `A` or `B` show up, whether they are in `id1` or `id2`, right? And then (b) if `id1 = A` and `id2 = C` co-occur on another row, and `id2 = C` has a different valid email address, it should also show up everywhere `A` or `B` or `C` is present, right? There's no direct relationship between `C` and `B`, but there is between `A` and `B` and between `A` and `C`, so `B` and `C` are connected through `A`, so same emails for all 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255808/discussion-between-paloma-rangel-and-gregor-thomas).